airflow on ecs to spark on k8s (EKS) connection setup on different AWS accounts
I have airflow running on aws ecs instances while my spark cluster is installed on EKS which is another account. So both airflow and spark on k8s (EKS) are running on different AWS accounts.
How can I setup connection so that airflow can submit jobs on another account EKS cluster and manage spark application
